# animation of progress bar using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to animate the progress bar gradually. When i use `for` loop, the progress bar disappearing

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        // Set the progressbar's initial value to 76%.
        $("#progressbar1").progressbar({value:7});

        // Set the progressbar's value to 18%.
        $("#button1").click(function() {            
            $("#progressbar1").progressbar("option", "value", 18);          
        });

        // Increment the progressbar's current value by 10%.
        $("#button2").click(function() {
            var val = $("#progressbar1").progressbar("option", "value");
        });

        // Decrement the progressbar's current value by 10%.
        $("#button3").click(function() {
            var val = $("#progressbar1").progressbar("option", "value");
            $("#progressbar1").progressbar("option", "value", val-10);
        });
    });
</script>


<input id="button2" type="button" value="Progress" />
```

So, when i click on Button 2, the progress bar has to animate gradually.

I will be more thank full, if some one help me to load the animation when page opens with `onload()` function
Please help me to animate the progress bar gradually and also it should load automatically when i open the file.

Regards,

Chandru.

Comment: ok chandru i got it all please follow the link http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/how-to-create-a-kick-ass-css3-progress-bar

Comment: You can check [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/progress/JQueryProgressBar.aspx).

Comment: Cache your jQuery result sets! `var $progressbar1 = $("#progressbar1");` You must provide some HTML markup for us to be able to help.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#progressbar').progressbar();

$('#button2').click(function(){
    makeProgress($('#progressbar'), 0, 100, 4);
});

function makeProgress(target, start, stop, steps){
    var step = (stop - start)/steps;
    var increment = function(){
        var val = target.progressbar("value");
        target.progressbar("option", "value", val + step);
        if (val + step < stop) setTimeout(increment, 500);
    };
    increment();
}
```

Comment: Hi Gor, that exactly what i wanted.. Thank you very much... i need one more help, can i have the progress bar animate automatically, when page load... It will be more helpfull, if you guide me to animate as per audio file(like HTML5 audio control, but without controls)

Answer (score 1):

By far not the best way (actually more a hack) but maybe you could look into the `.animate` jQuery function. Using a "dummy" css property it could look like this to animate the progressbar from a value of 0 to 100:

```
$('#progressbar').animate(
{ dummy: '100' }, 
{ 
  step: function(now,fx) { 
    // set current value
    $('#progressbar').progressbar('value', now); 
  } 
});
```

Edit: Example using one of jQuery's easing functions: http://jsfiddle.net/hPGNE/

Comment: Hi Cschleiden, that exactly what i wanted.. Thank you very much... i need one more help, can i have the progress bar animate automatically, when page load... It will be more helpfull, if you guide me to animate as per audio file(like HTML5 audio control, but without controls)